# Confusion related to derivative

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

What is the gradient of $||x + b||_1$ with respect to $x$? Here $x$ is the variable and $b$ is the constant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ to help you see it as a function of several variables. Then
$$
||x + b||_1 = |x_1+b_1|+\cdots+|x_n+b_n|.
$$

Now do you see how to find $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}||x+b||_1$?
Try $n=1$. What is the derivative of $|x+b|$?

Hint 2: It doesn't exist everywhere!

Comment: @all. I have found the answer. Sorry for asking something stupid. It was a trivial one